# Packaging a Node app from development to production

Tags: node.js, package

Apologies for the broad scope of the question and if there is a better sub for this question please let me know.

So my requirement is that we want to make sure that the Node app that is developed by the dev team goes through testing, QA, and production without any changes, very deterministically.

The strategy is simple:
Package the Node app and digitally sign it. This package will go through testing, QA, and production.

One of the requirements of this strategy is that when we go to the production server, we do not want to do `npm install`.

`[Pkg][1]` seemed to be the silver bullet until I found out it has trouble packaging the `BigNumber` library.

The other alternative seemed was doing `npm pack`. However, I found out that when I do `npm install package.tgz` it actually downloaded from the internet, and not actually package everything in it.

So I would like to ask for advice on how we can move a Node app from dev to production guaranteeing that we deploy the exact same package/binary that was built originally.
I understand `Docker` is the obvious choice, but we are trying to find out other ways that going down the Docker route.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Surprised pkg didn't work.  What's the issue with BigNumber?

Comment: @JimB. Gives an error with BigNumber. Issue raised here: https://github.com/zeit/pkg/issues/768

Comment: the '1n' notation is new to me, but it looks like it wasn't always in node.  Check to see if you're building for a recent node runtime?

Comment: @JimB. The app runs fine without any issue. And I have passed `--targets host` so `Pkg` uses the host versions. Thank you.

Comment: BigInt support (n suffix) is pretty recent in node.  I'd try to be explicit in the runtime selection with pkg, or at least print out the node version in the resulting executable to be sure it's >10.12.